# Reload Value $_SESSION - PHP + AJAX

Tags: javascript, php

i have a page called

" index.php "

where have some forms that users can fill it , after this when click at "Submit" all my form its send via AJAX to another page called

"download.php "

this is how i send the form , via AJAX:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#button_final').hide();

    function enviar(arg1,arg2){

        document.getElementById('qtamostra').value = arg1;
        $("#warning_alerta").hide();
        $("#input_vazio").hide();
        $("#login_erro").hide();

        var formData = new FormData($('#form_principal')[0]);
        $("#loading").show();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.ajax({url: "/tkclientespdo/etiquetaslog/carrefour/cumbuca/download.php",
                type: "post",
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                async:true,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(result){
                    if(result == 1)//logado
                    {
                        //$("#hide").show();
                        //$('#text_modal').html('Foi enviado 2 Etiquetas de Amostras');
                        $('#modal-container-188642').modal(arg2);
                    }
                    else if (result == 3)
                    {               
                        $('#modal-container-188642').modal(arg2);
                    }
                    else if (result == 300)
                    {
                        $("#login_sucesso").show();
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            window.location = "index.php";},3000);
                        }
                        $("#loading").hide();
                    }
                }
            )
        },300);
    };
</script>
```

on "download.php" , i have a variable that return the timestamp when the user click at " Send ".

```
$horaenviooff = date("dmYGis").'OFF';
```

after this , on "download.php" i have a code `$_SESSION['user_job'] = $horaenviooff` , that fill with the value .

after this , i made a `echo 3` like the following `$_SESSION['user_job'] = $horaenviooff;echo 3;`.

Where on "index.php" its showed a modal with $_SESSION['user_job'] , but , only show $_SESSION['user_job'] , if i reload the page index.php.

its possible for example , after `echo 3` , show a div at index.php with my $_SESSION['user_job'] ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can't access the `$_SESSION` variable directly, as $_SESSION lives on the Server while Javascript is a client-side technology. To get around this, one solution could be: Don't just write `$horaenviooff` to the `$_SESSION`, send it back to the calling AJAX function, too. You could for example let your "download.php" return JSON to easily transfer and access multiple values:

```
$response = [
    'result' => 3,
    'user_job' => $horaenviooff
];
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

You can then access the response's values in Javascript like:

```
/*...*/
success: function(response){
    if(response.result == 3){
        alert(response.user_job);
    }
} 
/*...*/
```